# Custom post-receive file using GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to replace my post-receive hook, auto-generated by GitLab by a new file which enables mail-support and thus has to be triggered "post receive".

This is the previous version of my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This file was placed here by GitLab. It makes sure that your pushed commits
# will be processed properly.

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  # For every branch or tag that was pushed, create a Resque job in redis.
  repo_path=`pwd`
  env -i redis-cli rpush "resque:gitlab:queue:post_receive" "{\"class\":\"PostRe
ceive\",\"args\":[\"$repo_path\",\"$oldrev\",\"$newrev\",\"$ref\",\"$GL_USER\"]}
" > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

When I replace that file by a new one which includes the above mentioned lines at the end of the file, GitLab says: "Project has invalid post-receive file" in the admin area but emails are correctly sent.

Do you know how to handle that problem of multiple post-receive support. At the moment I don't know if the gitlab specific part of the file is correctly executed at all.

Thanks for help!

#### Update:

The scripts within the folders are invoked now by using the below mentioned solution (pull request). But I don't understand why the standard "post-receive-email"-script doesn't send any mails if it is included in the directory. It works fine if it is invoked directly as post-receive.

Don't know why I have to change the order, but the following works for me (even I don't know if resque jobs are now created properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

repo_path=`pwd`

if [ -d hooks/post-receive.secondary.d ]; then

  for i in hooks/post-receive.secondary.d/*
  do
      [ -x "$i" ] || continue
      # call the hooklet with the same arguments we got
      path=$repo_path"/"$i
      "$path" "$@" || {
          # hooklet failed; we need to log it...
          echo hooklet $i failed
          perl -I$GL_BINDIR -Mgitolite -e "log_it('hooklet $i failed')"
          # ...and send back some non-zero exit code ;-)
          exit 1
      }
  done

fi

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  # For every branch or tag that was pushed, create a Resque job in redis.
  env -i redis-cli rpush "resque:gitlab:queue:post_receive" "{\"class\":\"PostReceive\",\"args\":[\"$repo_path\",\"$oldrev\",\"$newrev\",\"$ref\",\"$GL_USER\"]}" > /dev/null 2>&1
done

exit 0
```

Comment: A bit dangerous: if `post-receive.secondary.d` doesn't exist, it will exit without calling the GitLab hook `resque:gitlab:queue:post_receive`.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint. Corrected this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update 2014, with GitLab *not* using gitolite anymore:

As [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520784/6309) by [Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli), there is now an official way to **[setup custom hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/667c0a909bde1cf71f21d8ec9768e98b1c489030/doc/hooks/custom_hooks.md)** (GitLab 7.5.0+, Nov. 2014).

> 1. Pick a project that needs a custom git hook.
> 2. On the GitLab server, navigate to the project's repository directory.
>      For a manual install the path is usually `/home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
>      For Omnibus installs the path is usually `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
> 3. Create a new directory in this location called `custom_hook`s.
> 4. Inside the new `custom_hooks` directory, create a file with a name matching the hook type.
>      For a `pre-receive` hook the file name should be `pre-receive` with no extension.
> 5. Make the hook file executable and make sure it's owned by git.
> 6. Write the code to make the git hook function as expected. Hooks can be in any language. Ensure the 'shebang' at the top properly reflects the language type.
>      For example, if the script is in Ruby the shebang will probably be `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

---

Original answer (January 2013)

This (allowing custom hooks) has been resolved with [pull request 555](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/555) and [commit 2245a6bbe](https://github.com/owindsor/gitlabhq/commit/2245a6bbeabb4ed25d7e209772df68c5c407b9f1), at the time where GitLab was using post-update hooks.

You need to declare a `hooks/post-receive.secondary.d` in your git bare repo managed by gitolite and GitLab.
Put all your post-update hooks in there.

You could modify the post-update hook posted by gitolite [following that model](https://github.com/netdata/gitlabhq/blob/4e17304e14b2f8910d8cda49f40fa5dc7f823812/lib/post-receive-hook): it will call all your post-update hooks if detected.

---

The issue is:

With Gitolite V2, GitLab finally delegated that management to Gitolite, because you could [declare post-update.secondary hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html), that Gitolite itself would call.

[With Gitolite V3, there is no longer any reserved hook](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks) (beside the update one in the gitolite-admin repo), so there is no gitolite "secondary" mechanism.
But GitLab (which now uses post-receive hook), hasn't yet updated its hook management to take into account that new reality (of gitolite not allowing anymore secondary hooks).

Comment: Well thanks for the hint regarding the commit. I added the additional lines to my ".gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive"-file which is on its part included in my bare via symlink. I added the directory and an "post-receive-email"-hook within my bares hooks-folder. The script is not triggered... :/

Comment: @JohnRumpel is "`.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive`" itselft triggered? If yes, some debugging of that script is in order (add a bunch of `echo`, to see what is actually executed). The true solution would be to open a new issue with GitLab, to check if they have taken this into account when they switched to gitolite V3.

Comment: Yes, it's triggered. I think it's a problem since post-receive links to .gitolite/hooks but my post-receive.secondary.d is individual and thus within the project itself. Is there any way to "link back" to this folder?

Comment: @JohnRumpel you need to modify the script to test for `~/repositories/${reponame}.git/hooks/post-receive.secondary.d` (taking advantage that the hook does extract the '`reponame`' in the same `post-receive` hook)

Comment: Well I used the repopath variable and concatinated the strings to use an absolute path. I verified that the post-receive script invokes the post-receive-email script. But there is no mail sent. When I use symbolic link to this mail-script instead, it works.What the... :/

Comment: @JohnRumpel I still can't get this to work, can you please elaborate more on how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

**Custom hooks**

GitLab recently added a custom hooks feature since the regular hooks are used internally: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/667c0a909bde1cf71f21d8ec9768e98b1c489030/doc/hooks/custom_hooks.md

Basically, you just create a `custom_hooks` directory in you bare Git repo and put the hooks in it, and GitLab makes sure they get run.

Comment: I have included that process in my answer for more visibility. +1

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution to this particular problem could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  # For every branch or tag that was pushed, create a Resque job in redis.
  repo_path=`pwd`
  env -i redis-cli rpush "resque:gitlab:queue:post_receive" "{\"class\":\"PostReceive\",\"args\":[\"$repo_path\",\"$oldrev\",\"$newrev\",\"$ref\",\"$GL_USER\"]}" > /dev/null 2>&1
  /path/to/your/hook $oldrev $newrev $ref

done
```

As far as the mail notifications are concerned, I suggest using [this](https://github.com/nacho/email-hook) email hook.
Alternatively, you could use [git-notifier](http://www.icir.org/robin/git-notifier/) and replace `/path/to/your/hook $oldrev $newrev $ref` with `/path/to/git-notifier/`

Comment: Interesting. More concrete than my answer. +1