# Can the "post-receive" hook in gitlab-shell still be used for a custom hook?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-post-receive, post-commit-hook, chiliproject

According to the content of the [gitlab-shell `post-receive`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/hooks/post-receive) hook, it's deprecated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file was placed here by GitLab.
# IT IS DEPRECATED NOW.
# All GitLab logic handled by update hook
```

But only for Gitlab specific logic or generally? Imho I should still be able to use it for e.g. my chiliproject post-receive hook that updates my repositories. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything specific in this regard, mostly due to the gitolite <> gitlab-shell transition in gitlab v5. I hope someone can shed some light on this…

### [edit]

The `post-receive` hook [was removed](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/commit/2537a0b24cac9206f282a071ba5e930aabfc3135) from gitlab-shell for v1.7.1. So the correct way is to either create a web-hook, modify carefully the update hook or watch the development of gitlab-shell more closely until custom hook support is implemented. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom post-receive file using GitLab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317452/custom-post-receive-file-using-gitlab)

Comment: Since GitLab 7.5.0 (Nov. 2014), this is now implemented (thank you Ciro Santilli for the heads up). See the update answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 2014:

[Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256561/can-the-post-receive-hook-in-gitlab-shell-still-be-used-for-a-custom-hook/16256672?noredirect=1#comment43470913_16256672) and in "[Custom post-receive file using GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520784/6309)" that there is now (GitLab not using gitolite anymore) a way to **[setup custom hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/667c0a909bde1cf71f21d8ec9768e98b1c489030/doc/hooks/custom_hooks.md)** (GitLab 7.5.0+, Nov. 2014).

> 1. Pick a project that needs a custom git hook.
> 2. On the GitLab server, navigate to the project's repository directory.
>      For a manual install the path is usually `/home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
>      For Omnibus installs the path is usually `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
> 3. Create a new directory in this location called `custom_hooks`.
> 4. Inside the `custom_hooks` directory, create a file with a name matching the hook type.
>      For a `pre-receive` hook the file name should be `pre-receive` with no extension.
> 5. Make the hook file executable and make sure it's owned by git.
> 6. Write the code to make the git hook function as expected. Hooks can be in any language. Ensure the 'shebang' at the top properly reflects the language type.
>      For example, if the script is in Ruby the shebang will probably be `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

---

Original answer (Apr. 2013)

That is a direct consequence of not using [`gitolite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309), and replacing it with `gitlab-shell` with GitLab5.x.

That is why you have [`gitlab-shell` Issue 14](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/14), about allowing custom update hooks.

For now, you would add to register that hook yourself for each repos on the Gitlab server, which isn't very convenient.

Comment: I see. And thanks for the link to the issue, must've read over it. But what is there against using `post-receive` the way it's intended by git (as gitlab isn't using it anymore obviously)?

Comment: @nietonfir `update` or `post-update` hooks... in either case, you would need to register them manually to the right repos, while gitolite was doing it for you before. Issue 14 is about restoring that feature.

Comment: I think that issue might have been implemented. Answered on possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27520784/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilli thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.